# Mean displacement of an active brownian particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, brownian-motion

I am facing difficulty in a relatively simple integral. I have an active brownian particle with the equation of motions:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}= v \cos\phi+\sqrt{2D_T}\zeta_x
$$
$$
\frac{d\phi}{dt}= \sqrt{2D_R}\zeta_{\phi}
$$
Here $D_T$,$D_R$ are the respective translation and rotation diffusion coefficients, $\zeta_x,\zeta_{\phi}$ are the respective white noises with zero mean.
I am trying to calculate $\langle x(t)\rangle$.
This comes out as
$$\langle x(t)\rangle=\frac{v}{D_R}[1-\exp(-D_Rt)]$$

If someone could help me through the steps of this mean calculation, it would really be helpful. The starting direction of the active particle is along the $x$-direction.

Answer (score 3):

One gets by averaging the first equation of motion :
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\langle x\rangle = v\langle\cos\phi\rangle
$$
On the other hand, Itô's lemma implies
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\cos\phi = -D_R\cos\phi - \sqrt{2D_R}\sin\phi\,\zeta_\phi,
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\langle\cos\phi\rangle = -D_R\langle\cos\phi\rangle
$$
after taking the average and finally
$$
\langle\cos\phi\rangle = Ae^{-D_Rt},
$$
with $A$ a constant of integration. After plugging this expression into the first equation, we can integrate it, so that
$$
\langle x(t)\rangle = vA\int_0^t e^{-D_Rt} \,\mathrm{d}\tau + B = \frac{vA}{D_R}\left(1-e^{-D_Rt}\right) + B.
$$
Note that the initial conditions $\phi(0) = 0$ and $x(0) = 0$ will imply $A = \langle\cos\phi(0)\rangle = 1$ and $B = \langle x(0) \rangle = 0$ respectively.